# Rich text (with images) performance - UITextView vs UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to display rich text which may include a lot of images as is formatted as Markdown.

After some research I see that there are 2 most common approaches:

- parse **Markdown** to **HTML** and display it within `UIWebView`
- parse **Markdown** to  `NSAttributedString` and feed it into `UITextView` which can use `NSTextAttachment`s to display `UIImage`s.

I'm wondering about possible issues with both approaches but mostly performance.
I'm aware that with `UITextView` I'm a bit limited as I can't use CSS to customise its look etc., but if you had some experience and there are a lot of issues with images alignment in `UITextView` that would be good to know too.

Additionally, as this may be relevant to others searching for possible functionality, I'm listing libs that I'm considering to use to handle **Markdown**:

- [AttributedMarkdown](https://github.com/dreamwieber/AttributedMarkdown)
- [Bypass](https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass)
- [CocoaMarkdown](https://github.com/indragiek/CocoaMarkdown)
- [MarkdownTextView](https://github.com/indragiek/MarkdownTextView)

Answer (score 1):

With UIWebView you cannot get the frame size needed to display the content before it has been rendered (asynchronously). But with NSAttributedString you can get the bounds synchronously without first rendering the content. For this UIWebView is much slower.

I have used CSS with UITextView when converting HTML to NSAttributedString using DTCoreText. iOS has some own HTML to NSAttributedString conversion functions, but they are really, really slow.

Comment: I'm more thinking about insides of handling `NStextAttachment` using image displayed in `UIWebView`

But basing on this, the recommended approach would be to generate `NSAttributedString` with my own means (i.e. with some lib) and use it in the `UITextView`

Comment: One thing to note is that UIWebView can kind of lazy load the images asynchronously, but with NSTextAttachment you probably need more than just the url when setting the content to the UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends the use of UITextView where possible

> It’s recommended that you use a text view—and not a UIWebView object—to display both plain and rich text in your app.

Referene:
[UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview)

Also to customize the looks you can use any RichText Libraries, like 
[SwiftRichString](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftRichString)

Comment: It's worth noting that these days, NSAttributedString also has functions for loading rtf documents and rtfd documents (rich text with attachments) too.